# Cakephp - Model name disappeared after deployment

Tags: php, cakephp, deployment

I'm using Cakephp for my web application. In my view, I generate data table rows like this:

```
<?php foreach($initial_items as $item): ?>
<tr id="<?php echo $item['Metadata']['id'].'_movie' ?>" name="metadata_row" onclick="display_details(this);">
<td name='td_btn'><button id="<?php echo $item['Metadata']['id'].'_btn_row_remove' ?>" name="btn_row_remove" type="button"></button></td>
<td><?php echo $item['Metadata']['title']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $item['Metadata']['year']; ?></td>
<td><?php //echo $item['Metadata']['category']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $item['Metadata']['rating'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $item['Metadata']['file_path']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This works well for items like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Metadata] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 204
                    [vendor_id] => 1
                    [title_vendor] => Sony Pictures
                    [title] => NEW - Jurassic Park
                    [year] => 1993
```

This was developed on my localhost (XAMPP) server. When I deploy the code on actual host, I lose the Model name in my array. So it becomes like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 204
                    [vendor_id] => 1
                    [title_vendor] => Sony Pictures
                    [title] => NEW - Jurassic Park
                    [year] => 1993
```

so I can't do this any more:

```
$item['Metadata']['id']
```

Can anyone help by explaining why this happens on deployment? Do I need to change my code and use the index number instead of "Metadata"?

Comment: can you paste the code from the model?

Comment: ... from the and controller too